# Same Root Category (Default) shows on two different websites

Tags: magento-1.9, category, multistore

There are two URLs where I want to run my Magento Store with same Magento Installation:
1. http://www.antistaticesd.com
2. http://www.antistaticesd.com/business

First of all, I created a directory name `business` under my root on my FTP server:

[image]

Then, I created another website in the Magento back end, another store and another store view. Therefore there are two each:

```
WEBSITE: main website (Code: base)  
MAIN WEBSITE STORE: (Root Category: Default Category)  
DEFAULT STORE VIEW: (Code: default)  

WEBSITE: Business Website (Code: business)  
MAIN WEBSITE STORE: (Root Category: Business Store)  
DEFAULT STORE VIEW: (Code: business_store_view)
```

[image]

This is the code I added to the `.htaccess` file in "business directory":

```
SetEnvIf Host .*base.* MAGE_RUN_CODE="base";
SetEnvIf Host .*magento_site_2.* MAGE_RUN_TYPE="business";
```

The file other than `.htaccess` is the `index.php` that I copied from root folder(`public_html`) to "business" directory.

[image]

[image]

[image]

THE PROBLEM IS AS FOLLOWS:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is probably helpful link for ya.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24869883/magento-multi-store-products-from-different-root-category-in-same-page-on-websit

Answer (score 1):

Change your .htaccess to a pattern like this:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/business/.*" MAGE_RUN_CODE=business
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/business/.*" MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

No need to set a new Env vars for the default as it will default to it when the pattern is not matched